# How to check if two elements has the same class name and make "if" statement?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

The goal is in topic. How to check if two elements can have the same class and if they have the same class execute "if" statement. Here is the [link](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/vNJVLZ?editors=101).

```
$('[data-string]').text(function() {
    var stringer = $(this).data('string'); 
    var option = $(this).find('.price-element').addClass(stringer);
   });
      if ($('.main').hasClass('check') && $('.depend').hasClass('check')) {
      $(".price-attr").addClass('good')
      $('.dependable').attr('disabled', true)
    }
```

Comment: Where is your class `depend`?

Comment: This code is not working? $('.main').hasClass('check') && $('.depend').hasClass('check') he should works.

Comment: @Sandeep Nayak, please see the link.

Comment: @ErmineSoft not working

Comment: @NeedHate: I could only see `dependable` class and not `.depend` class. Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change class depend to dependable

```
if ($('.main').hasClass('check') && $('.dependable').hasClass('check'))
```

Comment: if there are more than one element then.

Comment: @NeedHate, set answer as resolved - if it help you. (So other user will see that question is resolved)

Answer (score 1):

It should work now: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjMJVK?editors=1

Change the class name in your code from `depend` to `dependable`

Answer (score 1):

Try with `,` like this

```
if ($('.main, .dependable').hasClass('check')){
//code
}
```

It can help you to check more than one elements with same class name.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but your html doesn't have depend class that's why if is not executing try below code

```
if ($('.main').hasClass('check') || $('.depend').hasClass('check')) {
alert("executed"); 
$(".price-attr").addClass('good')
$('.dependable').attr('disabled', true)
}
```